# USART + DMA on STM32f103

Tags: stm32, uart, dma

I'm implementing receive UART through DMA. I wrote 7 bytes UART's data received to an uint8 array[7].

My code is:

```
HAL_UART_Receive_DMA(&huart1, recv, 7);
```

All seem to be ok at the beginning, but after a few hundred times, the data stored in recv array was shifted by one and this problem occurred continuously after a few hundred receive times forward. I configure DMA with circular and increment address memory mode. How can I fix it?

Comment: What does it mean "_shifted_"?

Comment: It means `recv[0] = recv[6]` and `recv[index+1] = recv[index]`

Comment: It will be quite difficult to figure as you use HAL libraries which are not very good. Write this using the bare registers - it is easier than using the HAL libraries, and you will have the full control.

Comment: Could you supply your initialization code for the UART and DMA?

Comment: You should consider that every byte on the line potentially will fail to transmit, especially with high baud rates. If this happens you either lose data or you get garbage data and this will shift your input location.